# TSQL Conditional IN Clause

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to do a Location Look up on my column like this...

```
Where [Location 1] IN(@Brooklyn , @Queens)
```

However if NO LOCATION is specified I want to do something like this...

```
Where [Location 1]  = [Location 1]
```

in other words, I want to return all the rows if no location(s) was specified.

This is what I tried so far & it works...there has to be a better way of doing it.

```
Declare @Queens varchar(100)
Set @Queens = 'Queens'
Declare @Brooklyn varchar(100)
Set @Brooklyn = 'Brooklyn'

select * from AIDE_AVAILABILITY_REPORT 
where 
(
[LOCATION 1] = (Case When @Brooklyn is Not NULL Then 'Brooklyn' End) OR
[LOCATION 2] = (Case When @Brooklyn is Not NULL Then 'Brooklyn' End) OR

[LOCATION 1] = (Case When @Brooklyn is Null Then [LOCATION 1] End) OR
[LOCATION 2] = (Case When @Brooklyn is Null Then [LOCATION 2] End)

)
AND
(
[LOCATION 1] = (Case When @Queens is Not NULL Then 'Queens' End) OR
[LOCATION 2] = (Case When @Queens is Not NULL Then 'Queens' End) OR

[LOCATION 1] = (Case When @Queens is Null Then [LOCATION 1] End) OR
[LOCATION 2] = (Case When @Queens is Null Then [LOCATION 2] End)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `CASE` expressions, make sure to use the `ELSE` part instead of letting it default to `NULL`. This will save you a line for each set:

```
where 
(
[LOCATION 1] = (Case When @Brooklyn is Not NULL Then 'Brooklyn' ELSE [LOCATION 1] End) OR
[LOCATION 2] = (Case When @Brooklyn is Not NULL Then 'Brooklyn' ELSE [LOCATION 2] End)
)
AND
(
[LOCATION 1] = (Case When @Queens is Not NULL Then 'Queens' ELSE [LOCATION 1] End) OR
[LOCATION 2] = (Case When @Queens is Not NULL Then 'Queens' ELSE [LOCATION 2] End)
)
```

I would rethink your variables. Instead of having variables named after each borough, perhaps having a single variable with the name of the borough would be better:

```
WHERE [LOCATION 1] = (CASE WHEN @borough IS NULL THEN [LOCATION 1] ELSE @borough END) OR
      [LOCATION 2] = (CASE WHEN @borough IS NULL THEN [LOCATION 2] ELSE @borough END)
```

Comment: sirde, this would definitely save me few lines, cant really rename variables, i am working on a existing system.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider this approach :

```
if object_id('Locations') is not null drop table Locations

Create table Locations 
(
    location nvarchar(100) 
)

insert into Locations values('Brooklyn')
insert into Locations values('Queens')
insert into Locations values('Manhattan')
insert into Locations values('Bronx')
insert into Locations values('Staten Island')


Declare @locationlookup table 
(
    location nvarchar(100)
)

Declare @locations nvarchar(max)
Set @locations = ',Brooklyn,Queens,' 

if @locations <> '' 
    insert into @locationlookup 
        select location 
            from Locations 
                        where charindex(',' + location + ',', @locations) > 0  
else 
    insert into @locationlookup select location from Locations

select * from 
    AIDE_AVAILABILITY_REPORT a, @locationlookup b  
    where 
        a.location1 = b.location
        OR a.location2 = b.location
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time I've see this kind of issue I've used ISNULL like this:

```
SELECT * FROM AIDE_AVAILABILITY_REPORT 
WHERE ISNULL([Location 1],@Brooklyn) IN (@Brooklyn,@Queens) 
   OR ISNULL([Location 2],@Brooklyn) IN (@Brooklyn,@Queens)
```

However you seem to think the variables could be null (given your example), I would do that like this:

```
SELECT * FROM AIDE_AVAILABILITY_REPORT 
WHERE [Location 1] IN (ISNULL(@Brooklyn,[Location 1],ISNULL(@Queens,[Location 1])
   OR [Location 2] IN (ISNULL(@Brooklyn,[Location 1],ISNULL(@Queens,[Location 1])
```

Comment: @Brooklyn is a parameter it is easy to check if it is not null -- but I wouldn't expect it to be so.

Comment: why wouldn't you expect it to be? Granted, we don't have a lot to go on, but based on the OP's SQL, it appears that either @Brooklyn or @Queens could be NULL, and if so, then we just want to do `[LOCATION 1] = [LOCATION 1]` (i.e., true). Your SQL does not do that.

Comment: @siride - I can't see the use case but I added that as an example